# Is there a Render Mode in DirectX11?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am working on implementing a directx11 version of our game engine. The engine is originally written in `OpenGL 2.x` and there is an API that sets the render mode using `glRenderMode`.

Is there something similar in DirectX11 and if yes, can you please provide some reference to the API ? And if not, how should I implement this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Direct3D does not have built-in "picking" which is what OpenGL uses this ``glRenderMode`` to implement. See this [FAQ](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn pardon me for this dumb question : what exactly is picking ? I am newbie in graphics programming so trying to learn as I go. Is there a way to implement this in direct3D ?

Comment: I got the "what is picking?" part :) but would appreciate your feedback on how I can go about getting this implemented using Direct3D. thanks

Comment: Basically you are responsible for implementing a picking algorithm yourself instead of having one built-in.  For example, see this [tutorial](http://rastertek.com/dx11tut47.html)